# Background Image of Search bar is looking weird in iOS7 but looking fine in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7, uisearchbar

Hi I have installed my app in iOS 7 and I found a weird look of `UISearchBar`. In iOS 6.x the `UISearchBar` looking fine. No issue. I am attaching my search bar images with this ques. please direct me what is wrong in my implementation. Have apple deprecated or add something? I am stuck off but did not get any solution yet. I have read the UI Transition Guide also for iOS7 but everything in vain.

Image for iOS 6:

[image: Image for iOS 6]

Image for iOS 7

[image: Image for iOS 7]

**Edit:**

And i am setting background Image of `UISearchBar` in my `viewDidLoad:` method.

```
contactsSearchBar.backgroundImage=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.2,0,0.2,0)];
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please add some code how you are setting in viewDidLoad

Comment: I have added code that how I am setting UISearchBar background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue. I have just change the `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` method of UIImage with `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:`

```
contactsSearchBar.backgroundImage=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.2,0,0.2,0) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Dont know why this is working on iOS7. before iOS7 my implementation as asked in question is working fine. But thing is now its solved.Its late but I am happy.

Enjoy Coding..!!

Answer (score 4):

You should also set SearchBar's ScopeBarBackgroundImage property to the same image name that you set for searchBar background to have a consistent look.

```
[self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_bar.png"]];
[self.searchBar setScopeBarBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_bar.png"]];
```

Make sure you have set searchbar barTintColor property to clear color and Translucent Property to No.
Acc to Apple Documents in iOS 7 you can either set barTintColor property plus Translucent property OR BackgroundImage Property.